# Keep getting error of having undefined variable when it is defined in php. (-fix my code- dump)

Tags: php

I have some code that should change file permissions via ftp recursively, can anyone see the error? I keep getting back "connection not defined" when it clearly is.  Assume that

```
$ftp_server = $_POST['server'];
$ftplogin = $_POST['login'];
$ftppass = $_POST['pass'];
```

are defined (because they are)

```
function recperm($dr, $connection) { 
    //connect to ftp and change file permissions of a directory recursively
    $ftp_server = $_POST['server'];
    $ftplogin = $_POST['login'];
    $ftppass = $_POST['pass'];
    if ($connection === false) {
        die('Can\'t connect to ftp server'); 
        //end the script if connection not possible
    }
    $dra = array();
    $obj = scandir($dr);
    foreach ($obj as $objs) { 
        array_push($dra, $objs);
    }
    foreach ($dra as $dras) {
        ftp_chmod ($connection, 0777 ,$dras);
    }
    isdir($obj, $connection);
}

function isdir ($array, $connections) { 
    // function to start recursion into directories for function recperm
    foreach ($array as $objs) {
        if (is_dir($objs) == true) {
            recperm($objs);
        }
        else {
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Pieces of my code that use this function are the second function included and

```
recperm($dir, $conn_id);
```

where $dir is set to the current working directory

Comment: So which variable is undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling recperm and you forgot to put the $connection parameter on the call

Try this

```
    function isdir ($array, $connections) { 
       // function to start recursion into directories for function recperm
        foreach ($array as $objs) {
            if (is_dir($objs) == true) {
                recperm($objs, $connections);    <----- change here
            }
            else {
                die();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! there were a few other errors as well that I spotted when i saw that one :)